# how to use Exif API in Tizen Web Application

Tags: tizen-web-app

to handle image that display vertical, i'm using `[exifInfo.orientation = "ROTATE_XXX";]`. `exifInfo` is belong to `Exif API`. how to use `Exif API` in `Tizen Web Application?` While I click on "For more information about how to use Exif API, see Exif Guide." on `developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-references/web-application`, that page show nothing.

Comment: And did other basic functions of Exif API work for your app ?

Comment: I'm newbie so I don't how to add the library Exif API, could u tell me the way to add Exif API in tizen web application?

Comment: Which device are you using for your app ?

Comment: I'm using both Emulators mobile-2.4 and real device Samsung Tizen Z2

Comment: check my answer

Comment: thanks for answer. but I don't know how to implement Exif API in my project. "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exifInfo" while Debugging

Comment: have you run my code ?

Comment: I did but debugging shows "resolve() error occurred: NotFoundError with message: PLATFORM ERROR "

Comment: Put a image (image1 or anything you like) in the images folder of your 'My File' or File System

Comment: this one images/image1.jpg

Comment: so your problem is solved i think

Comment: thanks a lot. that code works fine. I solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tizen enables you to access and modify EXIF information in a JPEG file. The [Exif API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application?redirect=https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/3.0.0/org.tizen.web.apireference/html/device_api/mobile/tizen/exif.html) is mandatory for both Tizen mobile and wearable profiles, which means that [it is supported in all mobile and wearable](https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/web-application/media-and-camera/jpeg-file-exif-information) devices. All mandatory APIs are supported on the Tizen Emulators.

Use:

```
    var fileURI = "";
    var myNewExif = new tizen.ExifInformation();


    function getSuccess(exifInfo)
    {
        console.log(exifInfo.orientation);
        console.log(exifInfo.userComment);
        console.log(exifInfo.gpsLocation);
    }

    function resolveSuccess(file)
    {
       fileURI = file.toURI();
       console.log("Successfully resolved file: " + file.toURI());

       function onSaveSuccess()
       {
          console.log("Successfully saved EXIF information to JPEG file");
       }

       function onSaveError(error)
       {
          console.log("Error occurred:" + error.name + " with message:" + error.message);
       }

       myNewExif.uri = file.toURI();
       myNewExif.orientation = "ROTATE_90";
       myNewExif.userComment = "Photo taken on Golden Bridge in Sanfrancisco";
       myNewExif.gpsLocation = new tizen.SimpleCoordinates(50.086447, 14.411856);
       tizen.exif.saveExifInfo(myNewExif, onSaveSuccess, onSaveError);
       tizen.exif.getExifInfo(fileURI, getSuccess);
    }

    function resolveFail(error)
    {
       console.log("resolve() error occurred: " + error.name + " with message: " + error.message);
    }

    tizen.filesystem.resolve("images/image1.jpg", resolveSuccess, resolveFail);
```

Add these privileges in `config.xml`

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/content.read"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/content.write"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"/>
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"/>
```